# Accessing Arrays within a Dictionary

Tags: swift

I am new to IOS so this question may be for newbies. I know exactly what I want to do but the question is how to do it. I have JSON data of dictionary like to

```
{
    "restaurants": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to access the arrays within the Dictionary with this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in

        if let json = response.result.value {

            let RestaurantArray : NSArray = json as! NSArray

            for i in 0..<RestaurantArray.count{

                self.restaurant.append(Restaurant(
                    restaurantPicture: (RestaurantArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "restaurantPicture") as? String,
                    restaurantName: (RestaurantArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "restaurantName") as? String,
                    status: (RestaurantArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as? String
                ))

            }

            self.tableViewRestaurants.reloadData()
        }

    }
    self.tableViewRestaurants.reloadData()
}
```

and I am getting this error

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1032e6e98) to 'NSArray' (0x1032e7f28).
2018-04-16 11:58:29.020876+0000 restaurant[6262:210307] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1032e6e98) to 'NSArray' (0x1032e7f28).
```

I know what I am trying to do by accessing the arrays within the dictionary, but the problem is how to go about it. All helps and criticisms are welcome as I am ready to learn. Or is there a way I can try to get only the arrays from the database without it in the restaurants dictionary. Thanks all

Comment: `let RestaurantArray : NSArray = json as! NSArray` `json` according to your print is a `Dictionary`, not an Array. So `json["restaurants"]` is an array.

Comment: Please (learn to) **read** the JSON: `{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array. And don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift and don't use `as AnyObject).value(forKey:` at all. And it's highly recommended to decode the JSON with `Decodable`

Comment: Else, avoid using `value(forKey:)` usually debutants misuses it. Also avoid naming your var starting with an upercase. if you use Swift 3+, prefers Swift equivalents to NSStuff (NSArray, NSDictionary => Array, Dictionary), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
//As per above response


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in

        if let json = response.result.value as! NSDictionary {

            let restaurantsArray = json["restaurants"] as! NSArray

            for dict in restaurantsArray {

                let ID = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "id") as? Int
                //You can get more data like above
            }

            self.tableViewRestaurants.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1032e6e98) to 'NSArray' (0x1032e7f28)

**It clearly status that `response.result.value` is an dictionary, not an array.**

---

**FYI:**

Dictionary is represented by `{ }` and array by `[ ]` in JSON.

---

**Update your code as follows:**

```
    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let arr = json["restaurants"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        let RestaurantArray: [[String: Any]] = arr

        for dict in RestaurantArray {
            if let picture = dict["restaurantPicture"] as? String,
                let name = dict["restaurantName"] as? String,
                let status = dict["status"] as? String {

                let restaurantModal: Restaurant = Restaurant( restaurantPicture: picture, restaurantName: name, status: status)
                self.restaurant.append(restaurantModal)
            }
        }

        // Reload table view on main thread (UI related update)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViewRestaurants.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: on using your code I am getting this error           
restaurant[8453:295431] -[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc62d16490
2018-04-16 15:32:00.467625+0000 restaurant[8453:295431] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc62d16490'

Comment: @SamBanana, can you please refer on which line you are getting this error. As I can see I haven't referred `UIImageView` anywhere in my code. Perhaps you could use breakpoint to get where the error is

Comment: I have imageview in the tableview which should be used for displaying restaurantPicture: picture

Comment: @SamBanana, this problem is not related to parsing here. You need to make url from `restaurantPicture` by appending something in front and then load it, as you are getting image path in string. Also post the separate question for UIImageView related question or please update your question with related info.

Comment: Seems like, your problem is somewhere in your `UITableViewCell`'s code.

Comment: the problem is coming from the imageview that I am using to load the restaurantpicture

Comment: @SamBanana, please add the new question for this or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:

```
        var arrExtractedData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    if let jsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
        let arrRestaurants = json["restaurants"] as? [[String: Any]]

        for data in arrRestaurants {
            let tempDic:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

            let id = dict["id"]
            tempDic.setValue(id, forKey: "id")
            let restaurantName = dict["restaurantName"]
            tempDic.setValue(restaurantName, forKey: "restaurantName")
            let restaurantPicture = dict["restaurantPicture"]
            tempDic.setValue(restaurantPicture, forKey: "restaurantPicture")
            let status = dict["status"]
            tempDic.setValue(status, forKey: "status")
            let workingDays = dict["workingDays"]
            tempDic.setValue(workingDays, forKey: "workingDays")
            let workingHours = dict["workingHours"]
            tempDic.setValue(workingHours, forKey: "workingHours")
            arrExtractedData.add(tempDic)
        }
    }

    print(arrExtractedData) //Extracted Data
```

Comment: Why are you using NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary instead of Swift arrays and dictionaries?

Comment: @Moritz Please to know that, Can you please explain why should I not do.? Thanks for noting that

Comment: Revert the question and ask yourself why you're doing it. Swift has native arrays and dictionaries, why are you using those from Foundation? This is not Objective-C, you don't *have to* use Foundation. This is Swift, use Swift. // Main reason: preserve types.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Codable protocol. It really makes things easier.

Look, given this data

```
let data = """
{
"restaurants": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "restaurantName": "Chuks",
        "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
        "status": "Working",
        "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
        "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "restaurantName": "Chuks",
        "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
        "status": "Working",
        "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
        "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "restaurantName": "Chuks",
        "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
        "status": "Working",
        "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
        "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "restaurantName": "Chuks",
        "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
        "status": "Working",
        "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
        "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "restaurantName": "Chuks",
        "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
        "status": "Working",
        "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
        "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
    }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

And this struct

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let restaurants: [Restaurant]

    struct Restaurant: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let restaurantName: String
        let restaurantPicture: String
        let status: String
        let workingDays: String
        let workingHours: String
    }
}
```

You can easily get the array of `Restaurant(s)`.

```
let restaurants = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).restaurants
```